# In My Code There Is A Error Saying "Index Out Of Range" For Some Reason, I Actually Just Started Python And Hence Don't Know How To Solve This

Tags: python

```
for w in 'words':
 if w[4] == 'z':
      print(w)
```

In This Code At line 3, it says :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    if w[4] == 'z':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I can't Find A Solution To This, Please Try To Help

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this because in your code "for w in "words":" w represents the characters 'w','o','r','d','s' so if you are accessing the 'w'[4] It creates an error since there is no 4 the value in your character

```
for w in 'words':
 if w == 'z':
      print(w)
```

or you can have look on this

```
for w in range(len("words")):
  if words[w]=="z"
     print(words[w])
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is really valuable tool within python and many different programming languages. It allows you to select an element within a structure. [Read here](https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/). Your problem is that you cannot index the 4th character of a string with a single character.

In your code example, you are looping through the string 'words' and at each iteration, the variable w is populated with the each letter. So, at the first iteration w is 'w', then 'o', then 'r', and so on. So when you are indexing the w variable, you are asking for a letter that doesn't exist.

Try:

```
for w in 'words':
   if w == 'z':
     print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. You are trying to iterate the *string* **words** with **w**, so **w** is a *character*, but you are treating it like a *list*. You can try removing the **for** loop

```
if w[4] == 'z':
    print(w)
```